# Firing a MySQL trigger on existing table upon creation of trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with 2 columns named "Table1":
(Column 1 named "Col1" with the values: A,B,C,D,E,F)
(Column 2 named "Col2" with the values: 12,15,2,5,200,1).

I would like get all the values from column 2 to change to the value 1 if their value is lower than 100, so that column 2 will eventually look like this: 
(Column 2 named "Col2" with the values: 1,1,1,1,200,1).

I tried to create a trigger:

```sql
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER Table1upd BEFORE UPDATE ON Table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Col2<100 THEN
        SET NEW.Col2=1;
    END IF;
END;//

delimiter ;
```

When creating the trigger in MySQL workbench it says that the trigger was added but that 0 row(s) affected.

I assume my problem is with the BEFORE UPDATE choice, because the trigger does work when I update a value in the table, but I don't know what to change it to so that the trigger will also initially execute automatically when I create it.

Thank you in advance for any help,
D

Comment: 0 rows affected is what you often see when you execute DDL queries.  It doesn't mean there was ever a possibility that any rows could have been affected.  It is a side-effect of the way MySQL communicates, returning a row count, even in cases where no rows are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger only triggers on `UPDATE`, so you need a *second* trigger `BEFORE INSERT` to cover both use cases: update and insert:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER Table1insert BEFORE INSERT ON Table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Col2<100 THEN
        SET NEW.Col2=1;
    END IF;
END;//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: sorry, but it did not work for me. can you please clarify? as I understand it it will work on future records added to the table, right? I already have records in that table and they are not affected by adding the trigger you suggested. I want the trigger to alter the existing table records. thanx.

Comment: @theexplorer Clarification: a `TRIGGER` is only executed on event, i.e. when a new record is `INSERT`ed or an existing record is modified via `UPDATE`. To modify your existing records (independent of any event) you need to execute a query manually like: `UPDATE Table1 SET Col2 = 1 WHERE Col2 < 100`